# Electron white screen after built with log error not allowed to load resources

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am trying to package my Electron application by using electron-builder. But somehow after succesfully built, When run the application and it only showed the white blank scree. Then when check the console, there is an error like below, is it a problem cause by the build itself or come from the package.json, or from my directory. any hint ?  Thankyou

[image]

, Already tried many solution on the stack overflow and other place but not fixing the problem so I decided to add question.

I also attached my

> package.json

```
 {
  "name": "cookbook-dekstop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.common.js --watch",
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-builder"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-to-image": "^1.10.8",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "electron": "^20.1.1",
    "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "sass": "^1.54.8",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "cookbook-dekstop",
    "icon": "src/assets/cb.ico",
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist"
    },
    "extraFiles": [
      "./dist/assets/**"
    ],
    "files": [
      "./dist/**/*",
      "main.js",
      "preload.js"
    ],
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "dmg",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "portable"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> main.js

```
 var win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 800,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    icon: "./src/assets/cb.ico",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
    resizable: false,
  });

  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
```

The problem is you are trying to load an "external" resource that is packaged within a asar archive...

Comment: I am facing same issue with no console log but only for mac build. Works perfectly fine for ubuntu and windows build. I have tried both loadURL and loadFile.I have posted more details on this link : [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74036594/electron-js-electron-builder-mac-built-opening-blank-white-screen-when-run-whi)

Comment: I have found that when trying to debug paths in packaged builds.  It is helpful to write debug values directly to an output file using fs.writeFileSync() so you can inspect path values just like the console.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue with the use of  logs by using 
const appLogs=require('electron-log');
appLogs.transports.console.level = false;

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, the problem is after packing our app with electron builder, dist folder is missing inside app.asar file, so application cannot able to find the starting path. I found a way and that is actually working.

**Step 1 :** In your **angular.json** file change your **output path** to out/{your-app-name}

```
"outputPath": "out/{your-app-name}",
```

**Step 2 :** Change the path of loadUrl in **main.js file** as below

```
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/out/{your-app-name}/index.html`)
```

**Step 3 :** Now run this command `ng build --prod && electron-builder -w` , this will first build angular app and then it will pack using electron.

Hope this works, I faced this issue for 2 weeks, later I unzipped app.asar file and tried various things then found this working solution.